# Javascript - in browser data manipulation - fastest way to process

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following interesting problem.

I have monthly data for about 140 countries for the past 16 years (16 * 12 = 192 months).

The user can choose two dates: monthA and monthB.  The computer will then calculate the change in value between the two months for all the 140 countries.

My thinking so far is to pre-calculate the data using cumulative totals.  This will mean that if monthA = 20 and monthB = 100, the computer will just need to subtract monthB from monthA (i.e monthB - monthA) to get the change in value for each of the 140 countries.

While there are only 192 months, the number of combinations of the months result in n(n-1) /2 ==> 192(191)/2 ==> 18,336 combinations.  When multiplied by the number of countries, this equals: 18,336 * 140 = 2.567 million combinations.

These of course could be pre-computed and just loaded into the web-application at load time. But the file size would be quite large resulting in a longish load time for the page.

My thinking is to create cumulative totals for each country for each month: 140 * 192 = 26,880 elements to load from a file.  I am then thinking that the browser would then calculate the 2.567 million combinations and store these in memory.

The goal of this exercise is to have extremely fast response when the user selects different dates.  The context for this is in a D3 application where the user may use slider controls to very quickly select a range of dates (perhaps as many as 80 per second).

Does any body have a better appraoch...?

What javascript / D3 data structures will allow for the fastest response times...?

Comment: give some sample data structures if you will people can use in their answer, plus an example of a simple computation you're going to do.

Comment: Your user won't be able to see 80 images per second...

Comment: Also, ever thought of storing the data in database serverside, and doing an ajax poll for the data?

Comment: I would send selection (months A and B) to server and take results with JS and would write server-side script for calculations. I think that would be a lot faster in your case + you don't need to load data nor d3.js library on your site, so initial loading time shoud be better as well .

Comment: The calculations required are quite trivial -- they are simply monthB - monthA.  @dglugg you are correct that the user will not be able to see 80 images a second.  The images form part of an animation.  I know that the user will not be able to detect 80 pics a second...but I do not want to throttle the speed of the slider.

Comment: The computation described is not intensive. If you want interaction on the client-side as described, I would recommend loading the monthly data to the client and then doing the calculation in JS. Make an attempt and if it doesn't work or is too slow, come back and ask how to improve it.